# how to use Utils.FormIsOpen in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I need help using Utils in C#.

```
 private void manageUsersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Utils.FormIsOpen("ManageUsers"))// this line gives an error
            {
                var manageUsers = new ManageUsers();
                manageUsers.MdiParent = this;
                manageUsers.Show();
            }
                
        }
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 along with visual studio and I am trying to manage my users in the database while not physically adding them to the database but adding them at runtime.

Comment: If you want to work out whether a form is open, why not just retain a reference to it and ask it if it is visible, or search the Application.OpenForms collection for it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no `FormIsOpen` method in `Utils Class`.

If you want to check if a "ManageUsers" has been opened, you can call [`Form.MdiChildren Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren?view=net-5.0) to get all mdichildforms and filter them.

```
// get all child form
Form[] children = this.MdiChildren;

var query = children.Select(c => c)
                    .Where(c => c is ManageUsers).ToList();
if(query.Count == 0)
{
    var manageUsers = new ManageUsers();
    manageUsers.MdiParent = this;
    manageUsers.Show();
}
```